# create a listener that will listen to an external push server

Tags: android

is there any build-in mechanism in Android, which could create a service or app that actully listens to some server from the out side.. something that will "Wake up" the phone and makes him receaving a message from an outside server (i am asking this coz most of the appz are working the way aroound, when the phone sending requests to an outside server to recieve data)

is it possible any how ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. You app needs to poll the server.

Comment: but i heard something about XMPP ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility in Froyo to register your App for Intents that are sent do the phone from a remote server. Sadly this will only be a possibility if Froyo (Android 2.2) will become used on more phones. Also it could be possible that this intents can only be received while your screen is on.